# How to configure automatic pod reboot in Kubernetes if another pod reboots

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have two pods, after the first pod has rebooted, the other should automatically reboot after it. Pods are created using different deployments

Answer (score 2):

You can write down the script in python or any language which will look for the event for **POD** or **deployment** as soon as one gets restarted your script will **roll out** the deployment this way for the second deployment PODs will be **restarted**.

You can run the script inside one POD or as deployment which will continuously monitor the **Deployment-1** and restart the **deployment-2** if any changes occurred in **deployment-1**.

Example python client

```
import logging
import time
from kubernetes import client, config, watch
import json
import requests
import time
logger = logging.getLogger('k8s_events')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# If running inside pod
config.load_incluster_config()

# If running locally
#config.load_kube_config()

v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
v1ext = client.ExtensionsV1beta1Api() 

w = watch.Watch()

mydict={}

webhook_url = '';

while True:
    pod_list= v1.list_namespaced_pod("default");
```

further, you can write the logic for checking the **restart** count.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/

List of official libraries : https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/#officially-supported-kubernetes-client-libraries